# Extract only email and password from text file using PHP

Tags: php, file-handling

**I have an array which have  string kind of object I can say**

```
 Array
  (
[0] => Name=xyz
[1] => Email=xyz43@gmail.com
[2] => Password=xyz@123
[3] => Address=xyz University Lucknow
[4] => City=xyz
[5] => Name=peter
[6] => Email=peter43@gmail.com
[7] => Password=peter@123
[8] => Address=address
[9] => City=bla
[10] => Name=Jack
[11] => Email=jack76@gmail.com
[12] => Password=jack123
[13] => Address=jackAddress
[14] => City=jackCity
)
```

*desired output*

```
Array
(
[Email] => xyz43@gmail.com
[Email] => peter43@gmail.com
[Email] => jack76@gmail.com
[Password] =>xyz@123
[Password] =>peter@123
[Password] =>jack123

)
```

Let me confess that I want this stuff for login purpose thank you in advance .

Comment: Store the data in a better format such as JSON then you don't have to write your own parser

Comment: Your desired output is physically impossible. You cannot have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: @ADyson ectully this is result of  my (myFile.text). and I fetch that using file_get_contents method.

Comment: Ok. But my point was that if you have control over the contents of myFile.text, you should store the data differently to begin with, then you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like [this](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xscqa7jf)

```
$stringArray = ['Name=xyz','Email=xyz43@gmail.com','Password=xyz@123','Address=xyz University Lucknow','Name=xyz','Email=xyz413@gmail.com','Password=xyz1@123','Address=xyz University Lucknow'];
        
$loginCredentials = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($stringArray as $item){
    $data = explode('=', $item);

    if(in_array('Email',$data) || in_array('Password',$data)){
        $loginCredentials[$i][$data[0]] = $data[1];
        if(isset($loginCredentials[$i]['Email']) && isset($loginCredentials[$i]['Password'])){
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

//Output desired array
print_r($loginCredentials);
```

Comment: I have  stringArray which have multiple user info .and  its give me only last user info result..?

Comment: you can't have same name key , either you need to add a number at the end of the key or you need to create 2 different array emails [] and passwords []

Comment: As I said before I want to make login operation and for that I need to all users email and password . and my array is actually my (text) file. please suggest me what i do i really need to overcome of this problem.

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/php/3xscqa7jf check this let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes that's it. I want  thank you so much . let me do further process .